# Divs wont float in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-float

This would be the main markup:

```
<div class="mancha">
    <div class="logo"></div>    
    <div id="content-area" class="espacio">
             <div class="eltitular">HEADER</div>
             <div class="lacarta">LEFT CONTENT</div>
             <div id="sidebar">RIGHT CONTENT</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Where (allthough there are many more rules wich can be seen in the link this are the widths)

```
.espacio{
    margin-left: 192px;
    background: transparent;
        width:808px !important
}
.lacarta{
        width:595px;
        float:left;
}
#sidebar{
        width:210px;
        float:right
}
```

The problem is that .lacarta and #sidebar are not floating one next to other (this only happens in IE8 or lower)

It can be tested here: http://goo.gl/ksFQI (if you compare to firefox/chrome you will se that the sidebar is not in the right side of the container..)

I checked with the IE8 developer tools that the container seems to be big enough for both elements..

Any idea what I missed?

-EDIT-

Current IE:
[image]

Wanted (like in Firefox):
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, there is a bug in IE8 where right-floated elements seem to clear:left.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/right-floated-element-in-internet-explorer-8-is-positioned-differently-than-internet-explorer-7.aspx

If you don't want to add anything to your HTML at all, you can slightly restructure it for a quick fix. Put the right-floated `sidebar` first, ie:

```
<div id="content-area" class="espacio">
  <div class="eltitular">HEADER</div>
  <div id="sidebar">RIGHT CONTENT</div>
  <div class="lacarta">LEFT CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add parent container:

```
<div class="mancha">
    <div class="logo"></div>    
    <div id="content-area" class="espacio">
             <div class="eltitular">HEADER</div>
             <div>
                 <div class="lacarta">LEFT CONTENT</div>
                 <div id="sidebar">RIGHT CONTENT</div>
             </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this jsfiddle fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/hgrHq/

```
.lacarta{
    width:590px;
    float:left;
}
```

Just reduced the width of .lacarta a bit.

As an aside, you might want to consider a responsive grid system for laying out your coulmns like this. For example:

http://cssgrid.net/

http://semantic.gs/

Then you won't have lining up issues like this ... and it'll respond to all screen sizes.

Answer (score -1):

What exactly the Prob is...?? I just Tested the link and found those menu were not aligned .. and here the solution is `.menu li{ float:left}` .. for more jus put a screen shot if Possible :)